# Java transformation matrix operations

Tags: java, math, graphics, matrix, transformation

I'm trying to maintain and then use a transformation matrix for a computer graphics program. It's a 3x3 matrix that stores scale, rotate, and translate information for (x,y) points.

My program can handle any individual case... i.e. if I only scale or only rotate it works fine. However, it does not seem to work when combining scale and rotate, and I think that has to do with how I combine rotation and scale in the code. The matrix is called transformation and is of type float. The following methods clear, rotate, scale, and translate (in that order) the matrix.

```
public void clearTransform()
{
    transformation[0][0] = 1;transformation[0][1] = 0;transformation[0][2] = 0;
    transformation[1][0] = 0;transformation[1][1] = 1;transformation[1][2] = 0;
    transformation[2][0] = 0;transformation[2][1] = 0;transformation[2][2] = 1;
}

public void rotate (float degrees)
{
    double r = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
    float sin = (float)Math.sin(r);
    float cos = (float)Math.cos(r);
    transformation[0][0] *= cos;
    transformation[1][1] *= cos;
    if(transformation[0][1] == 0)
        transformation[0][1] = -sin;
    else 
        transformation[0][1] *= -sin;
    if(transformation[1][0] == 0) 
        transformation[1][0] = sin;
    else 
        transformation[1][0] *= sin;
}

public void scale (float x, float y)
{
    transformation[0][0] *= x;
    transformation[1][1] *= y;
}

public void translate (float x, float y)
{
    transformation[0][2] += x;
    transformation[1][2] += y;
}
```

For scale, the matrix hold info like this:

(Sx, 0, 0)
(0, Sy, 0)
(0, 0, 1)

for rotation, like this:

(cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0)
(sin(theta), cos(theta), 0)
(0, 0, 1)

for translation, this:

(1, 0, Tx)
(0, 1, Ty)
(0, 0, 1)

I don't think I'm correctly combining scale and rotate. Here is where I actually apply the transformation:

```
public float[] transformX(float[] x, float[] y, int n) {
    float[] newX = new float[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        newX[i] = (x[i] * transformation[0][0]) + (y[i] * transformation[0][1]) + transformation[0][2];
    }
    return newX;
}

public float[] transformY(float[] x, float[] y, int n) {
    float[] newY = new float[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        newY[i] = (x[i] * transformation[1][0]) + (y[i] * transformation[1][1]) + transformation[1][2];
    }
    return newY;
}
```

Where x and y are the pre-transformed point arrays, and n is the number of points

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Since it seems you are only transforming two dimensions, you can also use the Java2D `AffineTransform` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Comment: Nice, but `rotate` should be a matrix multiplication with the old values; the ifs on 0 have no right to be there. In general you would need a temporary matrix to write the new values into. Maybe you could borrow existing code from java.

Comment: I originally had those two as (*= -sin) and (*= sin), but in the event that they were 0, (which is always the case when applying the first rotation) then the values would remain 0.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct transformation should be:

[image]